# PuLP in Python Error of "/: Unsupported operand types for 'int' and 'LpVariable'" because I want to use my LpVariable for math operation

Tags: python, optimization, mathematical-optimization, linear-programming, pulp

I want to create an EOQ model in Python. I set my decision variable x as the EOQ value itself. But I use this value of x in determining my objective function (within the mathematical operation). But I get the error unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'int' and 'LpVariable'. For this reason, I cannot assign my order_cost_term and holding_cost_term values ​​that make up my objective function. How can I fix this?

```
import math

import pulp

# Data

weekly_demand = 7500  # Haftalık talep miktarı (kg)

order_cost = 27  # Her siparişin maliyeti (kg)

holding_cost = 3  # Her bir birim stok başına yıllık maliyet

confidence_level = 0.95  # Güven düzeyi 

z_value = 1.96  # %95 güven düzeyi için Z değeri (standart normal dağılım)

# Creating a mathematical model

model = pulp.LpProblem("EOQ_Optimization", pulp.LpMinimize)

D = weekly_demand * 52  # Yıllık talep

# Decision variable

x = pulp.LpVariable("EOQ", lowBound=0, cat='Continuous')

# Constraint (Order quantity must meet weekly demand)

model += x >= D, "Sipariş_Talep_Karşıla"

# Auxiliary variables

order_cost_term = (D / x) * order_cost

holding_cost_term = (x / 2) * holding_cost

# Define the objective function

model += order_cost_term + holding_cost_term, "Toplam_Maliyet"

# Solve the model

model.solve()

# Get results

EOQ = x.varValue()

reorder_time = EOQ / weekly_demand

# Adjust reorder time based on confidence level

standart_deviation = math.sqrt(reorder_time)

reorder_time = standart_deviation * z_value

# Print results

print("Optimal Order Quantity (EOQ):", EOQ, "kg")

print("Optimal Reorder Time:", reorder_time, "week")
```

I think I got this error especially for the division operation. So I tried to multiply the division but the result gave the same error. I made many changes on Line 22, for example, I changed its location or tried to add it to Lp as a model, but I could not solve my problem. I want to determine my objective function without error by using my decision variable in mathematical operation with integer and float values.

Comment: PuLP is for linear models only (the LP in PuLP hints at that). For nonlinear models you need other tools.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes `pulp` will complain if you put a variable in the denominator, even though the expression is still linear.  You could re-arrange your equation for `order_cost_term`, but that isn't going to help you because you are adding those 2 expressions together to make something of this form:

```
f(x) = a/x + bx
```

which is non-linear in terms of the variable `x`